# use SED to extract header and data from "x=a1, y=b1, z=c1" type of files

Tags: regex, sed

The data file looks like:

```
x=a1, y=b1, z=c1
x=a2, y=b2, z=c2
...
```

I want to parse it to a more useable format:

```
x   y   z
a1  b1  c1
a2  b2  c2
...
```

The header "x,y,z" and the data "a, b, c" does not contain "=" or ",".

using

```
 1 s/=*[^=]*[,$]/ /g
```

give me

```
 x y z=c1
```

Apparently the last item is not matched with "[,$]"  Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Dong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[,$]` matches either a comma or a dollar, not comma or end of line.

It is probably simplest to do two operations on the first line:

```
sed -e '1{ s/=[^,]*,//g; s/=.*//; }' ...
```

The first looks for everything between an equals sign and the first comma (including the delimiters) and deletes it, repeatedly; the second looks for everything after the last (only) equals sign and deletes that.

Comment: Jonathan, Very good! You also explained everything very clearly, much appreciated for a newbie.  Yes, my problem is with the [comma, end of line] matching.   One related question, how would you just strip the "=a1" and keep the comma, so the results would be a CSV file?

Comment: The standard way of showing thanks on StackOverflow and related sites is by either upvoting or accepting an answer or both (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)).  You can upvote by clicking on the up arrow beside an answer; you can accept by clicking on the tick mark (check mark) beside an answer to one of your questions.  Note that you get a small boost to your own reputation when you accept someone else's answer.

Comment: The replacement string (currently empty) should be changed to a comma to get CSV-like output.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's/[^=]*=\([^,]*\)/\1 /g'
```

Should be able to get all the data into this format

```
a1  b1  c1
a2  b2  c2
...
```

After that you can insert a header of your choosing with

```
sed -i 1i"header"
```

If you want you can also parse the header out of the file using the sed in Jonathan Leffler's answer.

Comment: `sed -e 's/[^=]*\([^,]*\)/\1 /g'  ` gives "=a1 =b1 =c1"

Answer (score 0):

To parse the file to CSV,

```
 s/=[^,]*//g

 s/[^,]*=//g
```

give header and data, respectively.